# Send file through serial port with Python

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I've made a program for communicate two devices through serial port with pyserial. I want to send and receive several files through the serial link. I've looked that this is possible to do with xmodem or kermit. Are there any way to do this without kermit/xmodem directly with python?

Comment: I agree with pr0gged. You should definitely not be shy to use a library to handle this kind of task unless you specifically want to implement it yourself for whatever reasons. Why do you want do it directly in Python?

Comment: I don't want to do this directly with Python. I wanted to know if this is possibly with Python. I'll try with xmodem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [xmodem](http://packages.python.org/xmodem/xmodem.html) package?

Otherwise you should implement a (simpler) checksum protocol on your own.

My opinion is that using some standards could enable you to better integrate with other (external) software, one day...

Comment: I've seen that this package can send files over the serial port. I'll take a look at this package.

Comment: Great. Please accept this response if it's useful to you. Thanks.